# ASP.NET MVC Form POST is very slow for large nested checkbox list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, data-binding

I'm having a problem with my ASP.NET MVC web application where it takes ~30 seconds for my `ViewModel` to hit my controller when the form is posted. I'm guessing it has to do with the default Model Binder because of this.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ByActivityEditViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) // Takes ~30 seconds before even hitting this
    {
```

My `View` is a series of nested checkboxes of `Group` parents and `User` children. The same `User` may be listed under multiple `Groups`. I'm using an `EditorFor` to generate the checkboxes for the `ViewModel`.

**View's Editor Template Call:** `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Groups)`

**Editor Template:**

```
@model MyProject.Models.Group
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Guid)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsAllowed, new { @class = Model.Guid.ToString(), @style = "margin-right:5px; cursor:pointer;" }) @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsAllowed, Model.Name, new { @class = "build-checkbox-label", @style = "font-weight:normal; margin-top:-2px;" })

@if (Model.Users.Any())
{
    <ul style="list-style:none;">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Users.Count; i++)
        {
            <li>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Users[i].Guid)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Users[i].Name)
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model.Users[i].IsAllowed, new { @class = Model.Users[i].Guid.ToString(), @style = "margin-right:5px; cursor:pointer;" }) @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.Users[i].IsAllowed, Model.Users[i].Name, new { @class = "build-checkbox-label", @style = "font-weight:normal; margin-top:-2px;" })
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class ByActivityEditViewModel
{
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public IList<Group> Groups { get; set; } = new List<Group>();
}

public class Group
{
    public Guid? Guid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DistinguishedName { get; set; }
    public string SamAccountName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public bool IsAllowed { get; set; }
    public List<User> Users { get; set; } = new List<User>();
}

public class User
{
    public Guid? Guid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DistinguishedName { get; set; }
    public string SamAccountName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public bool IsAllowed { get; set; }
    public bool IsUserChecked { get; set; }
}
```

**ModelState:**

[image]

The Model State contains the Guids, Names, and IsAllowed values.  I believe processing this is the slow part.

**There ends up being:**

- 64 Groups
- 853 Users

The user can be part of more than one group.

**I've tried:**

1. Using string for Guid and Parsing it later.
2. Removing BeginCollectionItem package I was using.
3. Yelling at my monitor.

Any suggestions, information, or a workaround would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using any js/jquer libraries to decorate or validate ? You should propably try for example Chrome developer/debug tools and try to see what's goin on. Although, that is a lot of checkboxes for browser to handle.

Comment: @Niko It was jquery validation, which I don't need for checkboxes. Thank you!! I totally had tunnel vision on the model binder. If you post this as the answer, I will gladly give you the bounty. I'm sure it will help others in the future. I used `@{ Html.EnableClientValidation(false); }` to turn it off in the View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery/js functions have done this for me previously a couple times, when handling large number of controls and i have banged my head trying to figure it out. Now I know where to look first.

Answer (score 1):

So it is not clear from the post what is the fix unless you read the comments. So the answer is to add  @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(false); } before @using (Html.BeginForm())

This turns off default client side validation and makes you form post faster to the server. Ofcourse if you need client side validation, then this is not the solution. In my case, my form had 200 rows with checkboxes and I didn't need the client side validation. So this solution worked great for me.